# Use Two Named Functions, or One With Conditional Statements?

Tags: javascript

On click my program moves individual fruits between fruit_shelf & fruit_basket.

I'm not sure if I should use two separate functions, like: moveToBasket & moveToShelf, or if it's more efficient using just one function that takes care of both via the if / else condition.

**Version 1 uses one function with if / else:**

https://jsfiddle.net/pu8ye9bq/2/

```
  let fruit_shelf = document.querySelector('.fruit-shelf'),
    all_fruits = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li'),
    fruit_basket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');

  function moveBackFourth(event) {

    if (!fruit_basket.contains(event.target)) {
      fruit_basket.appendChild(event.target);
    } else {

      fruit_shelf.appendChild(event.target);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < all_fruits.length; i++) {

    all_fruits[i].addEventListener('click', moveBackFourth);
  }
```

**Version 2 uses two separate functions to move between basket & shelf:**

https://jsfiddle.net/73dnprx3/1/

```
  let fruit_shelf = document.querySelector('.fruit-shelf'),
    all_fruits = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li'),
    fruit_basket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');

  function moveToBasket(event) {
    fruit_basket.appendChild(event.target);
  }

  function moveToShelf(event) {
    fruit_shelf.appendChild(event.target);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < all_fruits.length; i++) {

    all_fruits[i].addEventListener('click', moveToBasket);
  }

  fruit_basket.addEventListener('click', moveToShelf);
```

The reason it's important to me to know, is that I don't want to continue using a bad practice, if one of these methods is superior.

Will one of these options give me trouble, or is it one of those situations where either method is fine?

Any input greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button), not jsFiddle, so everything (including markup) is here on site.

Comment: isn't this something for  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm seems like you're right, I've totally missed there was a specific review section, sorry :-/

Comment: @TJ. Crowder — okay, will do that the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a **lot** of fruit, it really doesn't matter, but the first is inefficient because it has to go searching for information you already know based on where the click was.

But you don't need two different functions, you can use just one:

```js
(function() {

  let fruit_shelf = document.querySelector('.fruit-shelf'),
    all_fruits = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li'),
    fruit_basket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');

  // Gets called with `this` referring to either `fruit_shelf` or `fruit_basket`
  function moveFruit(event) {
    this.appendChild(event.target);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < all_fruits.length; i++) {

    all_fruits[i].addEventListener('click', moveFruit.bind(fruit_basket));
  }

  fruit_basket.addEventListener('click', moveFruit.bind(fruit_shelf));
})();
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  min-height: 6em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="fruit-shelf">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>

<ul class="fruit-basket">

</ul>
```

Technically, that uses **three** functions, because `bind` returns a new function. But from a maintenance perspective, you just have to maintain `moveFruit`.

(If you don't want to use `this`, just use `.bind(null, ...)` and accept where to move the fruit as the first argument.)

Comment: Damn I never thought about using bind. Thank you! One question, why wouldn't I want to use 'this'?

Comment: @Capax: No reason. It makes some folks uncomfortable to use `this` for something other than the DOM element in an event handler, but it's absolutely fine to do so.